# Jenkins extended choice parameter groovy script read json file

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Jenkins Extended Choice parameter allows to set a default value using Groovy Script.
Is there a way to read that value from a json file, which is located on a slave machine where the job is running? This file is stored outside of the workspace.

The following script doesn't work.

```
import groovy.json.*
def version_file = "/etc/configs/version.json"
def version = readJSON file: version_file
return version.VERSION
```

[image]

This script works

```
return "my value"
```

[image]

It seems Jenkins doesn't provide any logs for Groovy Script, which is used to setup a parameter value.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Go to **Manage Jenkins** -> **System Log** -> **All Jenkins Logs** and you will find the relevant logs for the groovy execution.

Comment: Thank you. It definitely helps, but doesn't provide an answer to my questions. 
I need to read a json file, which is located on the slave machine where the job is running. I can read this file from the pipeline with no issues, but I need to access it before the run to set a default value for one of the parameters.